# Graph of a log function using TikZ/pgfplots package with a vertical slope is missing data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs, function

I have a problem using the TikZ/pgfplots package in LaTeX.
I need to graph a function like this:

```
$y=-\log_{10} (0.5\cdot (-x+\sqrt{x^2+4 \cdot 10^{-14}})$
```

And I have been using this code without results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{a}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(0.1*(#1-50)/(50+#1))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{c}{1}{\pgfmathparse{-log10(0.5*(-#1+(#1^2+4*10^(-14))^0.5))}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
width=150mm,
height=100mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

    \Large $y=-\log_{10} (0.5\cdot (-x+\sqrt{x^2+4 \cdot 10^{-14}})$
\igskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
  xlabel = {$V$},
  ylabel = {$pH$},
  clip=false,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=14,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=100,
  ]

  \def\a{}
    \addplot[
    domain=0:100,
    samples=200,
    unbounded coords=discard
    ]
    { c(a(x)) };
  \end{axis}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The graph is cut near x=50, almost when the slope became vertical.

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: The comments of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237731/184389) might also be of help.

Comment: Not sure the dupe at time of writing is a particularly good match, but [pgf doesn't really have `10^{-14}` precision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637845/106162).  When `a(x)` becomes negative (x>50, your image doesn't seem to match the code) you're taking the log of something which is `\approx 0` (the `4e-14` isn't enough to guarantee the square-root is larger than `x` within pgfmath).  As logged (`NOTE: coordinate (1Y5.025e1],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump).`) these values are then getting dropped.

Comment: [How to get set the precision of the PGFPLOTS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637792/106162) or [Pgfplots and pgfmathparse, lack of precision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505300/106162) or [pgfplots - insufficient precision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305582/106162) are probably better dupe candidates, but even with [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) you might be borderline.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!
Finally, after several tries and errors, I change the compiler to LuaLaTEX and it works!